# How to get the difference of nested maps in groovy?

Tags: groovy, maps, difference

How to get the difference of nested maps?  I cant figure out how to get it. In my map there are 2 elements: response1 and response2. In response1 it has 5 in size() and in response2 it has 3 in size(). I want to print out the difference in each element and the missing elements as well

My Code:

```
def map = [response1:[[code:PLACE1, date:20-Jan-2021,
[code:PLACE2, date:20-Feb-2021],
[code:PLACE3, date:20-Mar-2021],
[code:PLACE4, date:20-Apr-2021],
[code:PLACE5, date:20-May-2021]],
response2:[[code:PLACE1, date:21-Jan-2021,
[code:PLACE2, date:20-Feb-2021],
[code:PLACE3, date: 20-Mar-2021]]]


def diff1 = map['response1'].minus(map['response2'])
def diff2 = map['response2'].minus(map['response1'])

echo "${diff1}\n"
echo "${diff2}\n"
```

Actual Output:

```
[[code:PLACE2, date:20-Feb-2021],
[code:PLACE4, date:20-Apr-2021],
[code:PLACE5, date:20-May-2021]]


[[code:PLACE2, date:20-Feb-2021],
[code:PLACE3, date: 20-Mar-2021]]
```

Expected Output:

```
[[date:20-Jan-2021],
[code:PLACE4, date:20-Apr-2021],
[code:PLACE5, date:20-May-2021]] 

[[date:21-Jan-2021],
```

Comment: would you be so kind to post a COMPILABLE code?

Comment: Even if I update this to be compilable, it's not clear what you're expecting.  Are you assuming maps are always in the same order?  Is the "code" value the key?  Why would your expected output not have a "code" portion for PLACE1?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are after is some kind of `minus` function that can be used for nested Maps and Lists. Here is a method that produces the expected result using recursion.

```
def minus(left, right) {
    if (left == right) {
        assert left in Map || left in List
        return left.getClass().getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()
    } else {
        switch (left) {
            case Map:
                if (!(right instanceof Map)) {
                    return left
                } else {
                    return left.findAll { k, v -> !right.containsKey(k) } \
                           + left.findAll { k, v -> right.containsKey(k) && v != right[k] }
                                    .collectEntries { k, v -> [k, minus(v, right[k])] }
                }
            case List:
                if (!(right instanceof List)) {
                    return left
                } else {
                    return left.withIndex().with {
                        it.findAll { val, index -> index < right.size() && val != right[index] }
                                .collect { val, index -> minus(val, right[index]) } \
                        + it.findAll { val, index -> index >= right.size() }
                                .collect { val, index -> val }
                    }
                }
            default:
                return left
        }
    }
}

def response1 = [[code: "PLACE1", date: "20-Jan-2021"],
                 [code: "PLACE2", date: "20-Feb-2021"],
                 [code: "PLACE3", date: "20-Mar-2021"],
                 [code: "PLACE4", date: "20-Apr-2021"],
                 [code: "PLACE5", date: "20-May-2021"]]

def response2 = [[code: "PLACE1", date: "21-Jan-2021"],
                 [code: "PLACE2", date: "20-Feb-2021"],
                 [code: "PLACE3", date: "20-Mar-2021"]]

assert minus(response1, response2) == [['date': '20-Jan-2021'], ['code': 'PLACE4', 'date': '20-Apr-2021'], ['code': 'PLACE5', 'date': '20-May-2021']]
assert minus(response2, response1) == [['date': '21-Jan-2021']]
```